# Preloader with Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, preloader

I've tried making a pre-loader for my site, using various methods, but each time the Bootstrap Navbar still appears immediately. The pre-loader and the rest of the content load as expected.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After changing the navbar class from Static-Top to Static, I'm no longer having this problem.